# Folder-sync strategy with robocopy and a token-file

Tags: windows, backup, powershell, sync, robocopy

I work on two machines that I cannot synchronize over the network so I use a flash memory.

To synchronize them I created a powershell script that backups my working folder to the flash drive so that I can restore it later on the other machine with the same script but a different parameter.

Yesterday I made a mistake and I restored the contents of the flash drive to the other machine overwriting my work (fortunatelly didn't loose much).

But *thanks* to this event I started to think how I could prevent this in future?

My idea was to pass a token-file from one copy to the other to mark which one is the latest and so that the script automatically knows whether it should backup (copy to the flash drive) or restore (copy to the machine) the files.

Do you think it's a good idea?

Do you have any suggestions how the token-file should look like or what I should put there? A timestamp? Or maybe should I change the timestamps of the file?

How should I maintain the token-file?

Or maybe you have any other ideas?

I'd rather not use a sync-software.

Comment: If you always `copy from` one machine and `restore to` another one, just add a check for `$env:computername` to your script and disallow the source to be used as a destination. It depends a little on how much logic you have in the script.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I copy from one machine to the other and back. I need to take my work with me and be able to continue on either machine. Sorry if the question isn't clear about it. Currently there is no logic in the script. I just call the script either with backup or restore and copy the folder to the flash drive or back. But if I accidentally call the wrong command (like last time) I'll overwrite my work with the last copy that was on the flash drive instead of creating a backup :-|

Comment: So you are updating files on both sides. What about having the PowerShell script to check whether there are any files newer at the destination than on the flash drive, and never start the copy process if that is the case. I don't think you need token files to implement this logic.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I think this might be a good idea. I need to test it with `get-chilitem` and some filters becasue there are over 45k files and it takes a while to find the newest ones.

Comment: So you are saying that sometimes the local machine files need to have their changes copied over to the USB and other times you need the USB file changes copied over to a PC drive?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT exactly... and precisely I take my work folder home when I want to work at home for a day or so, then I want to take it back to the office to continue there. I created a backup-script that I run before transfering the files to the flash-drive but it's still just a matter of time before I probably make a mistake again and overwrite my work with an older copy without having a backup.

Comment: @t3chb0t what about just comparing the `LastWriteTime`property of each file on server folder and flashdrive folder and then sync the newer file to the destination of the older file?

Answer (score 1):

Make 3 scripts, IN stands for In from USB, Out stands for Out to USB, LAst stands for last known good.
Make 3 folders on PC and on USB key, LAst, Current, Save or names that make sense to you.

- Running IN:

Current_PC > Save_USB

Current_USB > Current_PC

- Running Out:

Current_PC> Save_PC

Current_PC >Current_USB

- Running Last:

Current_PV >> Last_PC&  Last_USB

There is no need for token or .ini file with this approach.